# Stop form submitting more than once

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I've tried a number of things to stop the form from submitting more than once but nothing has worked. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
document.getElementById("submit-order-button").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var formValid = Object.keys(that.state).map(function(elem){
    if(that.state[elem] === "") {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })

  var emailValid;
  if (that.state.email.indexOf("@") > -1 && that.state.email.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    emailValid = true;
  } else {
    emailValid = false;
  }

  if (!emailValid || formValid.indexOf(false) > -1) {
    $("#validation-text").show()
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  } else {

  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Stop browser default behaviour
event.preventDefault();
```

**return true** is unnecessary. Use flag (1/0, true/false), for example, for count submitting attempts (and check (!) it before submitting).

Comment: I've tried that with no luck unfortunately. Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is that event.preventDefault() will only stop the form submitting if it's on a 'submit' event whereas my code is on a 'click' event

Comment: Recently I tried this variant and it works in FF and Chromium. Also you can define something like this inside your handler:
`document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { return false; };`
(keep in mind that `this` in inappropriate here)
Also you can add `type="button"` to your button tag to prevent default behaviour of button inside a form.